HydroSheds basins aren't importing to GRASS (cannot create attribute table)
Steps to reproduce the error:

Download any region from https://www.hydrosheds.org/products/hydrobasins 
Create a WGS84 location.
Try to import any .shp from HydroSHEDS Basins with a command v.in.ogr input=path_to_shp output=basin
See the error

Creating attribute table for layer <basin>...
DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
near "ORDER": syntax error

DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
near "ORDER": syntax error

ERROR: Unable to create table: 'create table basin (cat integer, HYBAS_ID
       integer, NEXT_DOWN integer, NEXT_SINK integer, MAIN_BAS integer,
       DIST_SINK double precision, DIST_MAIN double precision, SUB_AREA
       double precision, UP_AREA double precision, PFAF_ID integer, SIDE
       varchar ( 6 ), LAKE integer, ENDO integer, COAST integer, ORDER
       integer, SORT integer)'



Add the -t flag to command and see the error gone away.

What is the cause of this error and the solution?
I was expecting clean execution.

It seems that Integer64 or other digital format in HydroSheds Basins isn't read properly by GRASS
